# Searching for correct array syntax to match isset($options[self::SOME_PARAM])

Tags: php, arrays

I'm doing PHP right now. I'm trying to use a library that accepts options, in some method:

```
public function __construct(array $options = array())
{
    (...)
    if (isset($options[self::SOME_PARAM])) {
        (...)
    }
 }
```

On my side of code, I create this array like this:

```
array('SOME_PARAM'=>some_value);
```

Debugging, my array is there, but it never gets inside the if...

What am I missing in my syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this class is called, say, `LibraryClass`, then `SOME_PARAM` is a [class constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) accessed with:

```
array(LibraryClass::SOME_PARAM => 'some_value')
```

Answer (score 2):

`self::SOME_PARAM` is a const inside class, not a string.

Take a look at the documentation of [Class Constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) in PHP.